"MySQL Timezone Problem" Status alert: what test is run to display this alert?
I look after a number of CiviCRM implementations. Some of them display the System Status alert  about "MySQL Timezone Problem", and advise that timezone data needs to be loaded.
However when I raise this issue with my system administrator they confirm that timezone data has been loaded as described in the linked MySQL server documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html.
Presumably CiviCRM is running some sort of check to see whether the System Status alert should be displayed or not. Is this check reliable or is it prone to false positives? Why is it getting displayed on some of my CiviCRM installs (not all), when my sysadmin reports that timezone data is loaded on every server that we are using.
We run MariaDB on Debian.

It runs these two sets of queries. You could try them manually and see what happens:
SELECT CONVERT_TZ("2001-02-03 04:05:00", "GMT", "America/New_York");
SET @@time_zone = "Europe/Berlin";
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(981176700);

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/7e1617778fbaf1858aae25ca7511079024e7fa83/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Timestamps.php
